# What is the "opposite" of a grid icon?

Tags: icons, discoverability

I have a grid layout, and a list layout. I want the user to discover that they can switch between views -- i.e. no tutorial or anything.

A grid icon is pretty standard, so that can swap you into the grid view.

What about swapping from the grid view, and back into the list view? What is the best icon for that scenario?

Cheers.

Comment: There is a list icon actually http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/list-icon-63778.png
But it is against the rules here to ask for icon recommendations.

Comment: Icon requests are considered "off topic" here but a 10 second Google image search for "Grid List Switch" solves this: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=grid+list+switch&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw8cfs3r7bAhUIDMAKHYHXCWcQ_AUICigB&biw=1863&bih=1129

Answer (score 4):

Try these two simple icons. It is good to have text label on both theicons.

[image]